# (Ab)using Propensity Score Matching to Deanonymize data

Tags: propensity-scores, matching

Is there anything about simple 0-to-1.0 propensity scores (or other Matching technique) that might make it also good for deanonymization of a released dataset?

Specifically, can it be used to rebuild a sequential but re-randomized ID joining to another dataset which is hinted at by information from other features in a regression-equation-definable way?

**For instance:** If I have one **dataset A about group characteristics** that has an original ID and another **dataset B about the individuals** in groups.

I know the individual dataset B had the ID of the group from A but it now doesn't correspond at all (it was re-randomized). Even the sequence of individuals in B may partly relate to the group ID from A. I can still group by the re-randomized ID and the group averages of features from the re-randomized groups may also indicate matches to particular groups from A. Finally, I have a perfect, broad geographical region for both datasets.

I build a propensity score equation weighting all these ideas and try to guess (impute?) the group ID.

This is purely hypothetical. The challenge came up as a musing on a previous amicable collaboration. Could this just have a decision tree solution?

Comment: Do you know how the propensity scores were generated originally?

Comment: I would be the one to generate the score in order to sort and re-join the dataset A groups and dataset B individuals.